# Access wrapped object

Tags: c#, design-patterns, wrapper

I'm wrapping my ORM entities into bussines objects.

```
public class ProjectMember
{
    private readonly TfProjectMembersEntity _projectMembersEntity;

    public ProjectMember(TfProjectMembersEntity projectMembersEntity)
    {
        _projectMembersEntity = projectMembersEntity;
    }

    #region Props

    public string Email
    {
        get { return _projectMembersEntity.Email; }
        set { _projectMembersEntity.Email = value; }
    }

    public DateTime Created
    {
        get { return _projectMembersEntity.Created; }
        set { _projectMembersEntity.Created = value; }
    } 
}
```

This bussines objects are returned by the repository. The way out isn't complicated. The problem is how to access the wrapped entity when a wrapped object is passed to a repository for a save operation.

What would be a neat way, to get the wrapped object ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add a method or property?

You could create an Interface like so:

```
interface IWrappedEntity<T>
{
    T GetWrappedEntity();
}
```

Now you could make your BOs implement that interface. You could even create a base class implementing that interface and derive your BOs from that base class.

EDIT:
Changed DTO to Entity to conform with your code.

Comment: I'm looking for some generic way.

Comment: I guess , I cannot assure that this method can be accessed only from the repository ?

Comment: Hm, not really. What you could do: Implement the method explicitly, so whoever wants to access it, has to cast you BO to that IWrappedEntity interface. That way, the GetWrappedEntity method would not be available on instances of your BO directly.

Comment: What does it mean "Implement the method explicitly" could you please provide an example ?

Comment: Have a look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664591%28v=vs.71%29.aspx
Basically, an explicit interface implementation of that method looks like this: `TfProjectMembersEntity IWrappedEntity<TfProjectMembersEntity>.GetWrappedEntity(){ ... }`